# Is Default Package included in the Package Level Access?

Tags: java

I would like to know how the *default* package is defined in Java.I know how public and private access is defined but I don't know whether there is any *default* package access that is defined in **package level access** in java.

I'm asking this question because when I compile java file containing two classes since no modifier is given for classes,java compiler would give **package level access** as the default access modifier for the classes.Since no package is defined,java compiler would use the default package but I couldn't get whether the *default* package is included in **package level access** in java.Could anyone help me.

Comment: what is in tutorial that you don't understand? **[Java tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)**: "For convenience, the Java compiler automatically imports three entire packages for each source file: (1) the package with no name, (2) the `java.lang` package, and (3) the current package (the package for the current file)..."

Comment: @gnat:I would like to know whether **access** and **use** mean the same in context of programming.I'm having this doubt since I have two individual classes in a single java file and even after changing both classes to public I can't access one variable in another class.But as said in:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html ,it states that public access has **Y** for world that means any class can access an public class members isn't it?

Comment: what you describe sounds like nested classes ([Java tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)). Although without seeing your code it's quite [unclear what you're asking](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489)

Comment: @gnat:I'm not asking about nested classes but I'm asking about a class _followed_ by another.The code I'm asking is available on this post:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264423/whether-methods-could-be-defined-in-constructors-in-java. Could you help me in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The default package is the package without a name, all classes without a `package` declaration at the top of the file fall into it.

It is subject to all normal rules of packages except that you *can't reference* classes of it from a class inside a package.

For example I have 2 java files:

```
public class A{
    public static void foo(){System.out.println("fooCalled");}
}
```

and

```
package com.example;

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        A.foo();//won't compile
    }

}
```

Then B (or in the qualified form `com.example.B`) can never call the `foo` of A without reflection magic.

If you ever start making larger programs then you should put all your code in packages. It allows you to segregate your code in a way that makes sense.

The accepted practice is to name you package after a domain the program is part of like `com.example`

Comment: :Could you tell me what do you meant by "at the top of the file".Also I couldn't get what you meant by "you can't reference classes of it".By the second statement do you mean that we can't refer classes each other in the same package?That means if you have package `A` and have two classes `B` and `C` do you mean that you can't refer the method of `B` in `A` or vice versa?

Comment: :I have updated the post.Could you look at the post  and tell me whether _default_ package is included in the **package level access**.